# Unresolved import errors within a project

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, openpyxl

I have downloaded `openpyxl` and imported the project into Eclipse/PyDev. The openpyxl project does not build, giving Unresolved import errors on components with in the project, such as:

```
from openpyxl.styles import numbers
```

`Unresolved import: numbers`

I've tried including the source folders individually (shown below) but this doesn't help. Each of the source folders contains an "__init_.py" file. What do I need to do?

[image]

Comment: If you want to import `openpyxl.styles` you have to add the parent directory of `openpyxl` to the source folders.

Comment: Isn't that what the first line "/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}" is?

Comment: As I see `styles` as one of the subfolders, I guess that `${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}` is `openpyxl` and not it's parent folder.

Comment: Adding the parent folder is not an option.     
Going to Project > properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH > Source Folders > Add source folder  
shows that the highest one can select is openpyxl

Comment: Then you did not create/import the project properly. But you still have the option to add the folder as an external library.

Comment: Going to Project > properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH > External Libraries > Add source folder and then adding the folder above openpyxl has no effect.  I've tried importing the project using the project files that came with the download and also deleting those project files and creating a new project, but the result is the same with either.

Comment: But in general: Your way of using a library in Eclipse is only needed when you want to do do changes to it. If you install a lib with pip [https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/quickstart.html] it will be available in Eclipse automatically (maybe you have to click the Apply button in the interpreter screen). Even better is to have a virtual environment for python: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ . If you use that just choose the python binary from the environments `bin` folder as interpreter.